# Showing Safari Sidebar Only on New Tabs

Tags: macos, safari, bookmarks

Not long ago, prior to a software update (I don't remember which, but I think it was the one that introduced tab-groups), Safari would automatically show the sidebar on new tabs, but not on other ones (unless I manually toggled it).

After said update, Safari started showing the sidebar on all of its tabs. I.e., if I open a new tab, toggle the sidebar, and click a bookmark, the sidebar does not disappear like it used to.

Is there a way to revert to the original behavior? If not, is there another way I can automatically show all of my bookmarks on new tabs, but not on other ones?

Comment: I can't confirm your claim. I've checked back to Mojave & El Capitan. Sidebar is a global. It's either open or closed on all tabs.

Comment: I can confirm Rohan's claim. This is how I had Safari set up in Ventura on an older machine (since wiped). I also miss this feature.